# How do I vent 3 bathroom exhausts out the roof

Tags: bathroom, roof, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

I have 3 bathroom vents that all just vent into the attic. There is flexible pipe going toward the edge of the attic, as if it were going out a soffit vent, but there are no soffits here. So they are just venting the bathroom air to the edge of the attic.

What would be the ideal solution? My first thought was to get all 3 of them to go up to a single roof vent (the less holes I have to make in my roof the better) but I've heard that you can get the exhaust from one bathroom going into another instead of outside. Is there a good solution for this that would be somewhat simple?

Should they each have their own roof vent? If so, what is the ideal layout/spacing for these? do they have to be a certain distance apart? Is it better to have them be on the same level going across the roof or in a line going up and down the slope of the roof like in this picture? [image: (See picture)]

potentially going to use a roof vent like this one:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Broan-NuTone-Roof-Cap-with-Built-In-Damper-for-3-in-or-4-in-Round-Duct-in-Black-636/202191718

Any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated!  Really I'd just like to know the proper way to do this.

Comment: There are three parallel flexible ducts venting into the attic? Or are they manifolded together into a single outlet?

Comment: No soffit vents for the roof might be a bigger problem.  I usually prefer bathroom vent though the wall if possible.  Usually shorter and reduces holes/possible roof leaks, but depends.

Comment: @crip659 it looks like a gambrel roof, which wouldn't have soffit vents at that location.  Can't see enough of the lower section to tell if there are soffits.

Comment: Venting out the wall, if you can, is a lot easier to weather-seal and maintain.

Comment: @popham There are three separate ones venting into the attic.  one from downstairs, 2 from upstairs.

Comment: @crip659 I thought about going out the wall, but the point they enter the attic is right in the middle, so it would be about 17 ft in either direction to get to a wall.  Seems too long to me when the roof is less than 5ft straight up.  But maybe it's not? is it ok to run the ducts 17 ft to go out the side?
Why is lack of soffits a problem?  It's a gambrel roof

Comment: @keshlam I agree, but not sure if 17 ft is too long of a run. see my previous comment

Comment: Longer duct means a bit more resistance so the fan has to work harder. You might want to use rigid rather than corrugated duct to reduce turbulence and getting more efficient flow, and you might want to go with a slightly larger duct. Outside of that... Remember that much longer ducts exist in forced-air HVAC systems.

Answer (score 3):

The International Residential Code has [commentary for M1505.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/THPOTIRC2021P1/part-v-mechanical/THPOTIRC2021P1-Pt05-Ch15-SecM1505.2) that you should read. Technically that links to commentary from the ICC's International Tiny House Provisions, but it's a convenient paywall workaround for the same commentary. The commentary gives building officials the foundation to reject multiple fans that have been manifolded together. By my reading, the code advises building officials to accept manifolded fan venting if installed for a single family residence. For multifamily dwellings, again by my reading, the code advises building officials to reject manifolded fan venting.

On the adequacy of manifolded fans, here's a quick excerpt from that commentary:

> In some cases, installers connect the outlets of bathroom exhaust fans together to a common duct to avoid multiple roof, wall or soffit penetrations. This will result in some exhaust air flowing backward through the fan that is not running because the backdraft dampers in such fans will allow some leakage.

Is this "some leakage" acceptable performance? For a single family dwelling, the answer depends on personal sensitivity and backdraft damper quality.

Doing the work myself (and not paying the mobilization cost for somebody else to show up multiple times), my instinct is to install the system manifolded. If I don't like the performance, then I can just add a couple more roof vents.

If the system has been manifolded together all of this time, but just without an outdoor vent for the single flexible duct, then I would be much more comfortable with the single vent (assuming that you've been satisfied with the system's air-commingling performance up to this point).

Comment: Agree, and it's worth mentioning that modern bath extraction fans typically have a gravity and/or spring action damper that, more or less, eliminates reverse air flow.

Comment: @Jimmy, the linked commentary talks about the dampers, but you're right that their existence should have been explicitly mentioned here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  I'm leaning toward doing it this way.  The manifold or "splitter"  for 3 ducts going out 1 roof penetration.  You made a good point that if I didn't like how it was working, I could always add in 2 more.

Comment: Ad far as measuring whether I like the performance of the manifold solution, I'm not sure what I would do.  maybe stand in one bathroom while a hot shower is being run in the other to see if there seems to be any humidity coming in?  Maybe I should get some humidity sensors to quantify it.  Could be a fun experiment too.  Also considering additional backdraft dampers right before each of the 3 ducts enters the manifold.

Comment: @chen, I wouldn't worry about what little bathroom moisture comes through the backdraft damper. It's nasty smell that worries me. You could burn incense below each fan while the other/others was/were running. The smoke would give a visual indication of any air circumventing the dampers. Putting incense at the active fan, you could also subjectively smell test in other bathrooms in search of the incense smell. A single instance of the latter test would make subsequent tests difficult because of lingering smell from the earlier test.